# Need a formula that incorporates vlookup or similar

Tags: excel-formula

I need help with a formula that will list all of the unit #'s in a column based upon the results of 2 different columns.  The range for this is approx. 200 rows. Example:

```
A        B             C
Unit #   Inspection    Date
100      Pass          4/12/14
101      Pass          4/20/14
102      Fail          4/23/14
103      Pass          4/21/14
```

The formula would look at columns B & C and if it said "Pass" and the Date was within the last week, it would list the Unit # (for all 200 applicable rows). So the result would be in this format: 101, 103, etc.

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: That will be extremely difficult with a formula. It requires VBA. Why don't you just filter the list?

Answer (score 0):

Add two more columns, `Weeknum` in col D and `Extract` in col E; add below formulas:

`D2`:
=WEEKNUM(C2)

`E2`:
`=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,SMALL(IF(($B$2:$B$200="Pass")*(WEEKNUM(TODAY())-$D$2:$D$200<=1)*($D$2:$D$200>0),ROW($B$2:$B$200)),ROW()-ROW($B$1))),"")`

The formula in E2 is an array formula and needs to be confirmed with Ctrl+Shift+Enter.
This gives you `Unit#` of all `Pass` items which fall previous week or current week.

If you want to list only those falling in current week, change `$D$2:$D$200<=1` to `$D$2:$D$200<1`.